# Network manager ubuntu

Tags: networking

I am using Ubuntu in Virtualbox and not able to setup network connection to host windows7 machine. its showing wired network disconnected.
previously it was networkconnection1.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown virtualbox and go into settings then click on network and usually the settings in the screenshot that I am attaching are all you need.

You do not need to do anything in network manager in ubuntu.
[image]
If for some reason it does not work here is an image of the advanced settings.
[image]